# element 'stylesheet' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I need to validate an xml using below code:

Code

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl))); //Getting error on this line
```

XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" cdata-section-elements="true"/>

..
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried to google out for this error but could not found anything of much help. I am new to xsl and xml . Please let me know how can I get through this error.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The XML document supplied to the interface SchemaFactory.newSchema() should be an XSD schema document, but you seem to be supplying an XSLT stylesheet.

I'm not sure if this is a simple mistake in how you have invoked the API, or whether you have some fundamental misunderstanding about the role that XSD and XSLT play in processing XML documents.

Don't google for the error message, it won't help you. Before you write any more code, do some more extensive reading about the various XML technologies and their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is a programming language with XML syntax and defines its elements in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`. If you want to validate any XML document, then you need a schema to validate against, you seem to want to validate against a schema written in the W3C XSD (XML Schema Definition) language as you indicate that in

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

with the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`. However, in the next line of your code you would then need to pass in a schema in that namespace and not the XML instance document.

I don't think there is an XSD schema for XSLT 1, there is one for XSLT 2 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#schema-for-xslt) and one for XSLT 3 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsd11-schema-for-xslt). You would need to pass in such a schema to the `newSchema` call and then use that schema to try to validate your XSLT document.

However, as I said, you seem to be using XSLT 1 while those schemas are for later, much extended versions of XSLT so the schema based validation might not find problems which later an XSLT 1 processor might raise.